# Is the concept of justice circular?

Tags: definitions, justice

Hugo Grotius stated that “Justice…denotes nothing but what is just, indeed more in the negative sense than the positive, insofar as justice is that which is not unjust.”
Is this not circular?  A tautology of sorts?

Comment: Yes, if we read it as a definition it is circular; but we cannot define everything.

Comment: See [Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice): "Justice, in its broadest sense, is the principle that people receive that which they deserve"

Comment: @rux23 All you can say is that Hugo Grotius' definition of justice makes Hugo Grotius' concept of justice meaningless.

Comment: Humans are often in the position of preventing bad outcomes. We care more about catching people who cause harm than rewarding people who simply do what works. So we focus on the fewer cases of injustice rather than the vast majority of just cases. Makes sense to me.

Comment: Having said that may we have the reference to Grotius' text, please?

Comment: it is in book 1, chpt 1, section 3 of "The Law of War and Peace"

Comment: I've found the following text: "For *Right* in this Place signifies merely *that which is
just*, and that too rather in a negative than a positive Sense. So that the Right of War is properly that which may be done without Injustice with Regard to an Enemy."

Comment: seems I have a different translation...I am going off what is written in Schopenhauer's On the Basis of Morality (I believe Schopenhauer himself translated this passage into German, and then we have above is the English translation).   This translation seems to involve no circularity.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: "Justice is the set and constant purpose to give everyone their due." - Cicero

Answer (score 1):

Moral language in general is not reducible to non-moral language. You can define justice in various ways using terms like "deserving", "balancing the scales", "setting things right", etc., but then if you try to define those terms you will circle back to justice. However, this doesn't make moral language ill-founded; or rather, it doesn't make moral language any more ill-founded than any other subject matter. You can't define geometric terms without geometric terms, physical terms without physical terms, mental terms without mental terms, etc.

There are many domains of knowledge like this, and the only way to get people to understand each other is to discuss the concepts until they are all using the words in the same way. At that point, you can hope that there is a real meeting of the minds.

Answer (score 0):

Grotius’ definition is indeed circular, and useless. The question is why he did this to himself. In an extended section defining his terms, he never returns to this puzzling position.

After this quote, Grotius continues his analysis of justice and right. Here are the next two sentences of Section 3:

> Now any thing is unjust, which is repugnant to the nature of society,
> established among rational creatures. Thus for instance, to deprive
> another of what belongs to him, merely for one's own advantage, is
> repugnant to the law of nature, as Cicero observes in the fifth
> Chapter of his third book of offices; and, by way of proof, he says
> that, if the practice were general, all society and intercourse among
> men must be overturned.

[*The Rights of War and Peace,* Book 1, chapter 1 (Project Gutenberg)]

This definition, apart from whether one agrees with it, is noncircular.

Grotius’s (noncircular) discussion continues through Section 3, and then through Sections 4 to 17 (the translator omits Section 8). The nonsense definition that opens the section is left an orphan.

Comment: I agree (about the initial definition), but if we replace the word justice (as another poster stated) with another word we can possibly avoid this circularity?  Thanks for feedback!